# How to Copy SheetName and paste into a defined range?

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy the current Sheet Name and paste it into a defined Range?

My sheet name is always an 8 character date - ex: 03082021

The range of the current sheet to be pasted into is Y2:Y1000.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("Y2:Y1000").Value = ActiveSheet.Name`

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed to populate the dynamic range associated with the current region of data, which changes daily, I did this:

```vb
Public Sub Sheetname_Add()
'insert worksheet name into column Y

Range("Y1").Value = "TcktDate"

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0). _
Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Select

Selection.Cells.Value = ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```